# MWFeedParser removing the embedded media URL - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, rss

I have a page source info for the following url as below:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/thecarconnection/porsche

```
 <description>&lt;img src='http://images.thecarconnection.com/tmb/2013-porsche-panamera-platinum-edition_100405984_t.gif'/&gt; Best known for its legendary two-door sports cars, Porsche has branched out to the SUV and sedan fields in recent years. The company's first four-door car, the Porsche Panamera, has set tongues wagging and hearts yearning with its blend of unconventional style and blazing performance. While the Panamera range spans a broad scope, it competes...&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/thecarconnection/porsche/~4/_LggPvmEzJ4" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
```

I want to remove the 'img src='http://images.thecarconnection.com/tmb/2013-porsche-panamera-platinum-edition_100405984_t.gif'' link from from the description. I'm using the MWFeedParser which parses the URL as part of the description. Any suggestion on ways to remove the link within the description tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with this snippet, using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSString *description = ...;
NSError *error = NULL;

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression
        regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\&lt;img src='[^']*' */\\&gt;"
        options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSString *modifiedDescription = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:description
           options:0
           range:NSMakeRange(0, [description length])
           withTemplate:@""];
```